# Windows server 2008 hangs after restart from RDP

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, rdp

If I restart my windows server 2008 through Remote Desktop it hangs totally: no mouse cursor moving, or CapsLock switching. But it if I restart it locally, restart works fine. 
I don't find strange records in windows Error/Even logs.

What can be wrong?

Comment: At which stage during the restart is it hanging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstalling motherboard drivers resolved this problem.